# Online "database" for mathematical conferences?

Tags: mathematics, conference, online-resource

I am about to start applying for Ph.D programs (mathematics), and while compiling my CV, comparing it with many examples avaliable across the internet, I noticed that almost everyone attended one or two conferences during his bachelor/master years.
Now, I just didn't do that. I don't know if this could be an issue or anything, anyway, that is **not** my question.

Since I have at least four months until most programs start, I wanted to look for some conference that could be interesting. At my university there is a hallway where posters of such things are hanged, but I couldn't find anything online (apparently each university publishes its own conferences on its website, and that's it).

I can't believe there isn't an online equivalent of the above mentioned hallway, my question is: is there?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.ams.org/meetings/calendar/mathcal

Comment: Exactly. You may post it as an answer if you want. Anyway I will leave the question open for a while as I'm sure it is not the only one

Comment: I'm not involved with mathematics so I've answered with a community wiki in case others with more knowledge want to contribute to it.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to change the title of this question to include mathematics? i.e. 'Online "database" for mathematics conferences'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The American Mathematical Society has a calendar of conferences: http://www.ams.org//meetings/calendar/mathcal

As does the Mathematical Association of America: http://www.maa.org/meetings

And the Society of Industrial and Applied Mathematics: http://www.siam.org/meetings/

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to check:
http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-12-73665-0 - LNCS forthcoming proceedings
http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/index.html
http://www.acm.org/calendar-of-events
http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/

Answer (score 0):

We have a list of [Conference Announcement](http://www.exordo.com/blog/conference-announcement-sites-single-list/) sites on our blog. Hope this help.

(Caveat - it hasn't been updated in about a year)